Call JavaScript method taking a PHP value when clicking an HTML button with a value
My problem is that I want to pass a value of an  element to get the new value of $datosGraficas. Then, I want to update the graphs. I dont want to reload the page.

List of :

<a class="nav-link active" style="margin-top: 150px;" id="colesterol" data-value=0>Colesterol</a>
<a class="nav-link style="margin-top: 150px;" id="azucar" data-value=2>Azucar</a>
<a class="nav-link style="margin-top: 150px;" id="grasa" data-value=3>Grasa</a>


JavaScript:

document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach(function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach(link => link.classList.remove('active'));
        
        event.target.classList.add('active');

        var index = event.target.getAttribute('data-value'); 

        var datosDietas, datosCocinas, datosMinutos;
        var datosGraficas = <?php 
echo json_encode(recogerDatosGraficasAPI($list_requerimientos[indexForEach])); ?>;

        datosDietas = datosGraficas['dietas'];
        datosCocinas = datosGraficas['cocinas'];
        datosMinutos = datosGraficas['minutos'];
        actualizarGrafico(datosDietas, datosCocinas, datosMinutos);
    });
});


PHP is stateless and has to run server-sided while JS runs client-sided (with exception of Node). Once JS runs on the client side it has no direct access to the sever-sided PHP. The modern approach are dialog applications where you rite web services or APIs with PHP. Then you using a fetch and communicate between the client side and the server sided via JSON.

You have some basic syntax errors in your HTML - <a class="nav-link style="margin-top... You need to close the class attributes with double quote before beginning the style

If the amount of data is not excessive, you could stick it all into one data object, using the index number as key, and then pick the corresponding entry on the client side.
